# Directly get matched values of * (asterisk) using glob in Node.js

Tags: node.js, glob

Files

- /dir/w.txt
- /dir/x.pdf
- /dir/y.pdf
- /dir/z.pdf

Code

```
const glob = require('glob');
const pattern = '*.pdf';
const options = {
    cwd: '/dir/'
}
glob(pattern, options, (err, matches) => {
    // matches => ['x.pdf', 'y.pdf', 'z.pdf']
}
```

1. Is there any way to directly get the match array with the values of the * (asterisk) in the pattern '*.pdf'?
   **EDIT**: Regex is the standard way for matching strings. But, for patterns with a single asterisk, can I directly get the match array like:

```
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

2. Does the use of CWD in options **speed up** the matching?
   Like, I could have simply done it like this

```
const pattern = '/dir/*.pdf';
glob(pattern, (err, matches) => {
    // matches => ['/dir/x.pdf', '/dir/y.pdf', '/dir/z.pdf']
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Node.js doesn't *have* any in-built functionality for globbing. That requires that you roll your own, or pull in a [one of many] glob packages from NPM. And you don't say *what* glob package you're using.

I'm going to assume that it is [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob).

The reason for specifying the root of the search tree as the current working directory (`cwd`) is the matched paths are returned relative to the current working directory, so you noted:

```
glob('*.pdf', {cwd:'/dir/'}, cb)
```

hands `['a.pdf', 'b.pdf', 'c.pdf', ...]` to the callback, whilst making your glob expression an absolute path

```
glob('/dir/*.pdf', cb)
```

hands the callback absolute paths `['/dir/a.pdf', '/dir/b.pdf', '/dir/c.pdf', ... ]`.

It doesn't make it any faster. It's simply a convenience for the caller, depending on how much path information they need.

Note that you could just as easily have said:

```
glob('/dir/*.pdf', {cwd:'/path/to/something/'}, cb)
```

and you'd get the same `['/dir/a.pdf', '/dir/b.pdf', '/dir/c.pdf', ... ]` handed to the callback, because your glob expression is itself rooted/absolute.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I have added a glob import statement in the question.
Also, the answer from @theusaf is contradicting yours, please clarify

Answer (score 0):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the matches array to a new array which removes the extension and gets the top-level name:

```js
const pattern = '/dir/*.pdf';
glob(pattern, (err, matches) => {
    matches = matches.map((match) => {
        // this regex gets the name of the pdf file.
        return match.match(/[^/]+(?=\.pdf)/i)[0];
    });
    // matches => ['x', 'y', 'z']
}
```

The [`cwd`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#options) option is:

> The current working directory in which to search. Defaults to `process.cwd()`.

In your case, supplying a CWD might speed up matches as the program may not have to search through as many folders to find your matches.